# How to control the keyboard download event in iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, code-behind

I have a form in Xamarin with two `<Entry>` (entry controls) one of them, when doing Tap it opens a modal window that contains a list and the other has a normal operation, everything works well until the user opens the normal Entry keyboard first and then call the modal, when this happens the keyboard is up and the list is shown blocking the view of the user as follows...

[image: screenshoot]

I would like to change this behavior, so I attach the XAML code of the view

MyView.XAML:

```
      <Entry             
            Placeholder="Nombre Sustancia Química"
            Margin="15,5,15,5"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding NombreSustancia, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding EntryEnabled}">
        </Entry>


       <Entry    
            x:Name="Make"
            Placeholder="Seleccione Fabricante"
            Margin="15,5,15,5"
            Focused="Entry_Focused"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding NombreFabricante, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding EntryEnabled}">
       </Entry>
```

MyView.XAML.CS:

```
public partial class FiltrosSisquimView : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Fabricante> Fabricantes { get; set; }

        public FiltrosSisquimView ()
        {              
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private async void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            //prevents the keyboard from opening when calling the modal
            Make.Unfocus();          
            var mainViewModel = MainViewModel.GetInstance();
            Fabricantes = mainViewModel.Filtros.Fabricantes;
            mainViewModel.FabricantesModal = new FabricantesModalViewModel(Fabricantes);
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FabricantesModalView());
        }      

    }
```

I must say, that this problem only happens in iOS, and that Android has the expected behavior (when opening the modal the keyboard is automatically lowered), how could the keyboard go down when the user has already opened the list? Where should I control this event? on the modal page? in the codebehind? I am occupying MVVM as architectural pattern

any help for me?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I am implementing your solution, I will notify you in about 10 minutes @LucasZhang-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a native iOS design issue.I use the similar code on Xcode and get the same  issue.So you can use the `custom renderer`  and   to solve it.

> in Forms

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace app1
{
 public class MyEntry:Entry
 {
    public MyEntry()
    {

    }
 }
}
```

in xaml

```
<Entry      
    Placeholder="Nombre Sustancia Química"
    Margin="15,5,15,5"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       >
</Entry>


<local:MyEntry    
     x:Name="Make"
     Placeholder="Seleccione Fabricante"
     Margin="15,5,15,5" 
     Focused="Entry_Focused"      
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      >
</local:MyEntry>
```

> in iOS project

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using app1;
using app1.iOS;

using UIKit;
using Foundation;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace app1.iOS
{
  public class MyEntryRenderer:EntryRenderer,IUITextFieldDelegate
  {
    public MyEntryRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            Control.WeakDelegate = this;                       
        }

    }

    [Export("textFieldShouldBeginEditing:")]
    public bool ShouldBeginEditing(UITextField textField)
    {

        MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "finish");

        return false;
    }

  }
}
```

Now ,subscribe the message in your contentPage.

```
public partial class FiltrosSisquimView : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Fabricante> Fabricantes { get; set; }

    public FiltrosSisquimView ()
    {              
        InitializeComponent();    

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "finish", (obj) => {
        var mainViewModel = MainViewModel.GetInstance();
        Fabricantes = mainViewModel.Filtros.Fabricantes;
        mainViewModel.FabricantesModal = new FabricantesModalViewModel(Fabricantes);
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FabricantesModalView());
        });


    }

    private async void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        //prevents the keyboard from opening when calling the modal
        Make.Unfocus();          
        var mainViewModel = MainViewModel.GetInstance();
        Fabricantes = mainViewModel.Filtros.Fabricantes;
        mainViewModel.FabricantesModal = new FabricantesModalViewModel(Fabricantes);
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new FabricantesModalView());
    }      

}
```

Comment: This solution has been tested without success, although it has a lot of coherence with the written code because it is not able to hide the keyboard? Am I controlling the event in a good way? Any suggestions ...